# Mobile responsiveness queries

Tags: css, media-queries

This is okay on some phone and not okay on some others...This is okay on some phone and not okay on some others

```
     @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
      .body {
           width:100%;

       }
       }
       @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
         .all {
        width:100%;
        margin-top:0px;
        }
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
        .formm {
        margin-left:-17px;
        padding-left:35px;
        padding-right:35px;
        padding-top:70px;
        margin-left:;
        background-color:#24313c;
        opacity:0.8;
        height: 390px;
        width:360px;
        }
         }
```

Comment: check the phones width,that's why

Comment: I don't get you.

Comment: it depends on what phones  and screen sizes you want it to work on. there are still phones under 700px width in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question needs more details and clarity, btw you have to write many queries based on many screen sizes i mean you may change this line `(max-width: 700px)`  in each query

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite ambiguous.

There can be no 'Single media query for Mobiles', as Mobile displays come in various screen sizes and pixelations.

To build something responsive across multiple mobiles, you'll have to write queries for as many small screen sizes as you can think of!